# session always not null is jsp

Tags: java, jsp

```
      // login.jsp
                    <%
                        if(session!=null){
                            %>
                            <%@  include file="header2.jsp"%>
                            <%
                        }else{
                            %>
                            <%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
                            <%
                        }
                        %>

                        <form action="validate.jsp">
                        username:<input type="text" name="username"><br>
                        password:<input type="password" name="password" ><br>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit">

                        </form>

                        <%@ include file="footer.jsp"%>

            //validate.jsp

            <% 
            String username=request.getParameter("username");
            String password=request.getParameter("password");
            if(password.equals("password")){
                //HttpSession ses1 = request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("username", username);
                //response.sendRedirect("success.jsp");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("success.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }else{
                out.print("login fail");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("fail.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }

            %>
             //success.jsp
            <%

            if(session!=null){
                %>
                <%@  include file="header2.jsp"%>
                <%
            }else{
                %>
                <%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
                <%
            }


            %>
            <h2> success</h2>

            <% String n =(String)session.getAttribute("username");

            out.print("welcome"+n);
            %>

            <%@ include file="footer.jsp"%>
            //logout.jsp
              <%
              if(session!=null){
                %>
                <%@  include file="header2.jsp"%>
                <%
            }else{
                %>  
                <%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
                <%
            }
            %>  
            <%  
            session.setAttribute("username","");
               session.invalidate();
            %>
            <h2>You have been logged out</h2>

            <%@ include file="footer.jsp"%>
```

i am developing a simple jsp web application in which if the session is not null then it will include header2.jsp which consist a logout link else if the session is null then it will include only header.jsp which has login and register links ,but when i run this application it is always including header2.jsp which logout link,i don't why even the session is null also.please help here.

Comment: Because by default a session is always created. If you don't want a session add `<%@ page session="false" %>` to your page. Else you will always implicitly get a session. Also you shouldn't be programming in your JSP that should be done in a servlet instead. Scriptlets aren't a very good way of building a piece of software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless configured otherwise, a JSP page will *always* create a session.

You don't want to check for a null session; instead check for the presence of a known value in the session.

Unrelated, but all these scriptlets aren't a terrific idea.

Answer (score 0):

JSP page by default creates session, if there is no session. If you want to bypass creating the session you will need to add the following to your JSP:

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```